# While exporting KML from QGIS layer name is adding up before Name field, how to remove that?

Tags: qgis

I have prepared shapefile containing boundaries of land parcels and other required details. I want to export this plot boundaries along with the details mentioned in attributes in the exported KML file. While clicking on polygons, the name field is added up with layer name e.g. "Locations: front" in this, Locations: is my file name in which I have exported data. How can I specifically remove this file name/layer name tag from KML?